# Terminal backslash input repeated in output

Tags: command-line, zsh

I'm using zsh on a MacBook Pro, OS X 10.10. When I type in certain commands, such as this one:

```
cat myfile | awk -F $'\t' '{print $8, $9}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1n | awk '{if ($1 > 50) sum += $1} END {print sum}'
```

, then part of the command is repeated before the actual output of the command. The output in this case looks like:

```
    " '{print $8, $9}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1n | awk '{if ($1 > 50) sum += $1} END {print sum}' : myusername2525
```

Does anybody know how to get of the jumbled output? It kind of looks like a format string vulnerability or something similar to me.

Comment: The problem is the `$` in the first `awk` statement -- what are you trying to achieve with that that whole `awk -F $'\t' '{print $8, $9}'`? Are you really expecting your field separator to be a dollar sign followed by a tab character? Or are you trying to use `$` to denote the start of the line?

Comment: I dunno, I had some problems with the escaped tab character a while ago and some people put a dollar sign before strings with escaped characters, so I thought this was standard behavior

Comment: In any case, it's kinda strange that it just prints half the string back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `$` in the first `awk` statement in the chain:

```
awk -F $'\t' '{print $8, $9}'
```

The `-F` option for `awk` sets the record separator for your input. If you're really expecting the separator to be a dollar sign followed by a tab character you should move the dollar sign in to the single quotes like so:

```
awk -F '$\t' '{print $8, $9}'
```

Leaving the `$` outside the single quotes means it's being interpreted by the shell as a variable reference. This is what's leading to your weird output. If you aren't expecting a dollar sign in the field separator, only a tab, change the `awk` call to:

```
awk -F '\t' '{print $8, $9}'
```

Based on what you've said, the above appears to be what you want.